# Pass data from View Controller to Class?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller

**First, I'm not pass data between view controllers**. I need pass data from a View Controller to another class.

Situation likes this:

I have one View Controller, it has slider, then I have a Camera class. I defined a camera the Scene Class, once I change the slider, the value of the camera in the Scene class needs to be changed.

VC:

```
class ViewController: {
    @IBAction func moveSlider(_ sender: NSSlider) {
     // here I want to pass the sender.value to the Camera class
    }
}
```

Camera class:

```
class Camera {
    var cameraLocationX ; // I want this value updated once the the slider moved, however the camera instance is defined in the Scene
}
```

However, this Camera class are not defined in the VC. So I can't use the static var method...

```
class Scene {
    let camera = Camera()
    ..
    camera.cameraLocationX; // here it needs to be updated.
}
```

How to achieve this?  I Googled it seemed that I should use delegate or notification , but can someone give me a little more instructions?

Comment: Is that cameraLocationX var a static var? If so, you can change its value directly right?

Comment: humph, I forget about static, I can try with static.

Comment: Observer pattern comes to mind.

Comment: @BobMac, can you please elaborate that a little ?

Comment: This seems like a good place to start. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328361/Understanding-and-Implementing-Observer-Pattern-in

Answer (score 0):

Use the *delegation* pattern. This is a core concept described https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update property of class then you can set new value from your VC:

class ViewController: {

```
let camera = Camera()

@IBAction func moveSlider(_ sender: NSSlider) {
 // here I want to pass the sender.value to the Camera class
 camera.cameraLocationX = sender.value
}
```

}